How to create dotnet template which uses variables
I have successfully created a Visual Studio template according to this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli
However I can't figure out how to replace variables with real files locations.
I have 3 class libraries in my solution:

Application
Domain
Infrastructure

Domain does not have references, application layer has a reference to domain, and infrastructure has reference to application layer.
In application layer .csproj, I have:
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\$ext_safeprojectname$.Domain\$ext_safeprojectname$.Domain.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

and that variable $ext_safeprojectname$ is not being replaced with real location when the project is created.
I would like to put "Project name" here, from the wizard, so it should look like:
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProjectName.Domain\MyProjectName.Domain.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

The same problem appears in files that contains code.
The variables are not being replaced:
using $ext_safeprojectname$.Domain;

namespace $ext_safeprojectname$.Application
{

}

Because of that issues I can't run "dotnet pack".
It all work when I use old approach with zipping all files and putting it into Visual Studio templates folder however does not work with "dotnet pack".
